# Solution for processing lots of data with CRON/API, dealing with memory/timeout issues

Tags: api, wp-cron, cron, memory

Using a custom CRON job set up in my Wordpress site I am connecting to an external API to refresh some data. The API only allows for a certain amount of records to be read at a time so I have to "page" through, once one set of data is loaded then make another request to the API and load more, etc.

The problem is that this can quite often run out of memory or just go on too long and error out for large batches of data.

I am wondering if there is any kind of solution for "jobs" or "workers" in Wordpress, where after the first page of results is processed then submit another job for the next page and it's run as a second request instead of one long string.

Comment: You can disable WP-Cron  by adding `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` and use system cron and `wp_schedule_event` instead .

Comment: Thanks @AnoopD, this can still run into limitations on request time. Looking at how it can be divided up into separate request but started with a single, keep in mind the results are paginated so it has to work through all "pages".

Comment: Within what interval you intend to run the task ?